# Is there a way to select an unbroken series of requests each lasting a given duration?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I need to find any requests where 5 of them *in a row* take 30 seconds or more.

Is there a way to do this using a kusto query?

I guess it could be rephrased as 'if there is a request that takes 30 seconds or more to get a response, check if the next 4 requests also take 30 seconds'.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread -

[Check for the request where response time is higher](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d52a883-cdb7-46b0-aa1b-5e68503df9bc/azure-alert-for-those-requests-who-exceeded-from-particular-duration-application-insights?forum=ApplicationInsights)

Hope it helps.